# Why Common table expression does not work with INSERT SELECT

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, netezza

I am trying to use a common table expression in my INSERT.
When I do:

```
with A as (select col1,col2 from table1) select * from A
```

it works
But when I do:

```
with A as (select col1,col2 from table1) 
insert into table2 (col1,col2) (select col1,col2 from A)
```

I get:

```
found "INSERT" (at char XXXXX) expecting `SELECT' or `'(''
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should work with most databases.  However, Oracle and earlier versions of Postgres put the CTE next to the `select`.  So, if you are using Oracle, earlier versions of Postgres or Postgres-derived databases:

```
insert into table2 (col1, col2)
    with A as (select col1, col2 from table1) 
    select col1, col2 from A;
```

Also, there is no need for parentheses around the `select` query.  It isn't a subquery.

Comment: Thanks. I use netezza, which is postgres

Comment: Actually, Netezza and earlier versions of Postgres have the same limitation (i.e., `insert` doesn't support CTE but `select` does).

Comment: You are a genius! I will accept the answer  as soon as it allows me