# Does Trino (formerly Presto) INSERT work with CTEs?

Tags: presto, trino

I am trying to insert rows into a table with a query of this form:

```
with my_CTE as 
(SELECT a,b,c
FROM my_source_table
WHERE <some conditions to apply>)

INSERT INTO my_destination_table
SELECT a, b, c
FROM my_CTE;
```

This error appears:

*mismatched input 'INSERT'. Expecting: '(', 'SELECT', 'TABLE', 'VALUES'*

I know the CTE is written correctly because I can do other things with it.
I know the table exists with the columns available in the CTE because I can write to it, as shown above, with Hive.

Does [Trino](https://trino.io/) not support CTEs and INSERT to work together as shown above?

I have reasons for wanting to use Trino instead of Hive.

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737070/why-common-table-expression-does-not-work-with-insert-select).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the order of the CTE and INSERT backwards.

This works:

```
INSERT INTO my_destination_table

with my_CTE as 
(SELECT a,b,c
FROM my_source_table
WHERE <some conditions to apply>)

SELECT a, b, c
FROM my_CTE;
```

See the previous Stack Exchange Q&A in my comment above.

Comment: Great job answering your question. Go ahead and apply the green check mark to your answer! :)